# Find nested parentheses with regex

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

I have this string:

```
TABLEXY1((INITIALPARAM2*117.3/MADAD(2)),INITIALPARAM1+1)*PARAM2/100*(TABLE12(INITIALPARAM3)*PARAM3-(TABLE12(INITIALPARAM4)*PARAM4))"
```

i need to be able to get the TABLEXY1 with it values in the parentheses.
the posibble values in there are:

(number)

(expression)

(number,number)

(number,expression)

(expression,expression)

(expression,number)

i don't know how many parentheses to expect.

I have tried

```
TABLEXY1\(((?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)))\)
```

but it gave me

```
TABLEXY1((INITIALPARAM2*117.3/MADAD(2)
```

and not what i needed

```
TABLEXY1((INITIALPARAM2*117.3/MADAD(2)),INITIALPARAM1+1)
```

Comment: Use `TABLEXY1\((?:[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)`

Comment: Although .net regex does not support recursion, it can match nested structures with balanced constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If recursion is supported, then you could use:

```
TABLEXY1(\(([^()]|(?1))*\))
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/7aVWtL/1)

Since as far as I know C#'s regex doesn't support recursion. So instead you can just skip regex all together.

```
var str = "TABLEXY1((INITIALPARAM2*117.3/MADAD(2)),INITIALPARAM1+1)*PARAM2/100*(TABLE12(INITIALPARAM3)*PARAM3-(TABLE12(INITIALPARAM4)*PARAM4))";

int match = str.IndexOf("TABLEXY1");

if (match != -1)
{
    int begin = str.IndexOf("(", match) + 1;
    int end = 0;
    int parenthesisCount = 1;

    for (int i = begin; i < str.Length; ++i)
    {
        char c = str[i];

        if (c == '(')
            ++parenthesisCount;
        else if (c == ')')
            --parenthesisCount;

        if (parenthesisCount == 0)
        {
            end = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(match, end - match + 1));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
TABLEXY1((INITIALPARAM2*117.3/MADAD(2)),INITIALPARAM1+1)
```

Comment: This is a great technique for finding nested parenthesis.  I was able to use this expression in AutoHotkey to exclude commas that were not in nested parenthesis.  I posted a question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62806431/1898524).

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant to something like this?

"(?=TABLEXY1.+()\S+(?=*PARAM2.*)"

the answer I got is: TABLEXY1((INITIALPARAM2*117.3/MADAD(2)),INITIALPARAM1+1)

Comment: No, You can't be specific, i don't know what in the first (main) parenthesys. where did you check it? i don't get the same

Comment: powershell...  I didnt specify anything .. I said after you saw ( take everything until you see the word PARAM2..