# Regex replace character within match of nested parenthesis, or replace only within text outside of match

Tags: sql, regex, autohotkey

I'm writing an AutoHotkey script that will format SQL statements from text selected on the screen.  I want to turn a statement like this:

```sql
SELECT Name AS [Object Name], Switch([Type]=5,'Query',[Type]=-32768,'Form',[Type]=6,'Table') AS [Object Type], Switch([Type]=5,1,[Type]=-32768,2,[Type] In (1,4,6),6) AS [Object Type ID], Left(Name,4) as Prefix, LTrim(RTrim(Mid([Name],5,30))) as Suffix
```

into this:

```sql
SELECT Name AS [Object Name], 
    Switch([Type]=5,'Query',[Type]=-32768,'Form',[Type]=6,'Table') AS [Object Type], 
    Switch([Type]=5,1,[Type]=-32768,2,[Type] In (1,4,6),6) AS [Object Type ID], 
    Left(Name,4) as Prefix,
    LTrim(RTrim(Mid([Name],5,30))) as Suffix
```

I started by replacing commas with *comma+carriage return+tab* but when I encountered SQL statements containing functions using commas within parenthesis it produced undesirable results.  My first solution was to exclude commas within parenthesis, with this AutoHotkey RegEx command:

```
; Find commas not in parenthesis and suffix with <CR><Tab>
s := RegExReplace( s, ",(?![^()]*\))", ",`r`n" . Tab )
```

The problem is that sometimes parenthesis are nested, and that simple RegEx didn't work.

After some digging I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436342/1898524) a recursive RegEx that would select the outer most parenthesis of each group.

```sql
\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)
```

Now the challenge is,

1. how do I select everything outside of that group and find/replace within it, ***or***
2. how do I apply a search/replace to only text within that group?

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5WMlyI/4/)

SO encourages us to answer our own question.  In the process of writing this up I found a solution and I will post it below.  Feel free to share solutions of your own.  I would like to further my understanding of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I can use an *or* in my expression to find anything in parenthesis *OR* any comma.  With this method it won't select any individual commas that are inside the parenthesis groups.  (Thanks to *zx81* in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240972/1898524) post.)

```
 ,|\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)
```

With that expression I can use the substitution `|$0|` to surround each matching group with the `|` character.  Then it is easy to find the stand-alone commas with `|,|` and replace with my carriage return pattern, then replace all remaining `|`'s with an empty string.

```
; AutoHotkey snippet below
s := RegExReplace( s, ",|\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)", "|$0|" )
s := StrReplace( s, "|,|" , ",`r`n" . A_Tab )
s := StrReplace( s, "|" , "")
```

[Regex substitution example](https://regex101.com/r/5WMlyI/5)